# Mosquitto service won't start

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have an AWS EC2, Ubuntu-16.04 instance where Mosquitto is installed. I noticed that, the `mosquitto` process dies out and nothing apparent seems to be appear in the log `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`.

When I run this command, the service won't start!

`sudo service mosquitto start`

I don't know where to look for to understand what went wrong. Currently, I am managing with

`sudo -u mosquitto /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf &`

Any suggestions where to look for service start-up issues?

`systemctl status mosquitto.service` output

```
ubuntu@ip-172-xx-xx-xx:~$ systemctl status mosquitto.service
* mosquitto.service - LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mosquitto; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2018-07-12 07:56:54 IST; 5h 35min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6552 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mosquitto stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16941 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mosquitto start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 12 07:23:27 ip-172-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Started LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker.
Jul 12 07:56:53 ip-172-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker...
Jul 12 07:56:54 ip-172-xx-xx-xx mosquitto[6552]:  * Stopping network daemon: mosquitto
Jul 12 07:56:54 ip-172-xx-xx-xx mosquitto[6552]:    ...done.
Jul 12 07:56:54 ip-172-xx-xx-xx systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Comment: Just because it's not apparent to you doesn't mean it won't help the rest of us. Edit the question to include the log and the output from `sudo service mosquitto start` (and the output of `systemctl status mosquitto.service`)

Comment: Is the output from `sudo service mosquitto start` located at `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log`? I am pasting the output of `systemctl status mosquitto.service` above.

Comment: The systemctl output implies that mosquitto shut down cleanly. Run it again immediately after you've tried to start it (after killing your manually started version as well)

Comment: Also this is basic Linux Service management and not really a IoT question. Should really be asked on askubuntu or SuperUser

Comment: The restart - using `sudo service mosquitto start ` - never happened. Hence, this question. Also, yes, I agree this is basic Linux Service management. But, I was wondering if there was a `mosquitto` specific parameter to be checked.

Comment: Today, when the service stopped, I noticed that the latest entries (around 10 or so) were about saving database to `mosquitto.db`. My persistence settings have the database location set to a separate EBS volume and `persistent_client_expiration 8h`. Could this be a hint?

Comment: Have you solved this?  If not, do you have Apache running? Are you using SSL certificates for either the web server and/or mosquitto?